# Where do my cursors come from for my edges?

Tags: graphql

I have been trying to figure out how I want to implement pagination in my graphql api. I was thinking of following [Relay Cursor Connections Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm)

This is simple enough building something that looks like

```
{
  allFilms {
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        title
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
```

My question is around the cursor. I always thought the cursor was the equivalent of an id/primary key. From my reading it is not. It is a point/location in the connection.

Can someone explain to me what it is and where it comes from. Is this a NoSql concept? I am guessing when connecting to a relational database the cursor would be the id/primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this helps, but there is a short explanation here:
[In GraphQL what's the meaning of "edges" and "node"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622912/in-graphql-whats-the-meaning-of-edges-and-node?rq=1)

The `cursor` is a string to help identify where to include page breaks (or at least pagination which I take to mean page breaks) but perhaps that was already explained.

Comment: Ye following this, but my question is more around how is the cursor generated if it's not the id